# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (1,256,256,6)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I got an error,

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (1,256,256,6) .

I wrote codes in **main.py**

```
parser.add_argument('--checkpoint_dir', dest='checkpoint_dir', default='./checkpoint', help='models are saved here')
parser.add_argument('--sample_dir', dest='sample_dir', default='./sample', help='sample are saved here')
parser.add_argument('--test_dir', dest='test_dir', default='./test', help='test sample are saved here')
parser.add_argument('--L1_lambda', dest='L1_lambda', type=float, default=10.0, help='weight on L1 term in objective')
parser.add_argument('--use_resnet', dest='use_resnet', type=bool, default=True, help='generation network using reidule block')
parser.add_argument('--use_lsgan', dest='use_lsgan', type=bool, default=True, help='gan loss defined in lsgan')
parser.add_argument('--max_size', dest='max_size', type=int, default=50, help='max size of image pool, 0 means do not use image pool')

args = parser.parse_args()


def main(_):
    if not os.path.exists(args.checkpoint_dir):
        os.makedirs(args.checkpoint_dir)
    if not os.path.exists(args.sample_dir):
        os.makedirs(args.sample_dir)
    if not os.path.exists(args.test_dir):
        os.makedirs(args.test_dir)

    tfconfig = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
    tfconfig.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    with tf.Session(config=tfconfig) as sess:
        model = cyclegan(sess, args)
        model.train(args) if args.phase == 'train' \
            else model.test(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

In **models.py**

```
def sample_model(self, sample_dir, epoch, idx):
    dataA = glob('./datasets/{}/*.*'.format(self.dataset_dir + '/testA'))
    dataB = glob('./datasets/{}/*.*'.format(self.dataset_dir + '/testB'))
    np.random.shuffle(dataA)
    np.random.shuffle(dataB)
    batch_files = list(zip(dataA[:self.batch_size], dataB[:self.batch_size]))
    sample_images = [load_train_data(batch_file, is_testing=True) for batch_file in batch_files]
    sample_images = np.array(sample_images).astype(np.float32)
    sample_images = array(sample_images).reshape(1, 256, 256, 6)

    fake_A, fake_B = self.sess.run(
        [self.fake_A, self.fake_B],
        feed_dict={self.real_data: sample_images}
    )
    save_images(fake_A, [self.batch_size, 1],
                './{}/A_{:02d}_{:04d}.jpg'.format(sample_dir, epoch, idx))
    save_images(fake_B, [self.batch_size, 1],
                './{}/B_{:02d}_{:04d}.jpg'.format(sample_dir, epoch, idx))
```

Traceback says

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 53, in
>   
>       tf.app.run()   File "/home/ml/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
>   line 44, in run
>       _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))   File "main.py", line 49, in main
>       model.train(args) if args.phase == 'train' \   File "/home/ml/learning/pix2pix/CycleGAN-tensorflow/model.py", line 176, in
>   train
>       self.sample_model(args.sample_dir, epoch, idx)   File "/home/ml/learning/pix2pix/CycleGAN-tensorflow/model.py", line 215, in
>   sample_model
>       sample_images = array(sample_images).reshape(1, 256, 256, 6) ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (1,256,256,6)

Before this I got reshape error, so I added below code

`sample_images = array(sample_images).reshape(1, 256, 256, 6)`

But now I was told size 0 is causing error.I really cannot understand why this error happen. I do not think 0 size images are in the folder. How should I fix this? What is wrong in my code? Is any image has size 0 in the folder?

Comment: batch_files seems to be empty, or load_train_data() doesn't return anything

Comment: @Natecat You are right. 
batch_files is empty.But how can I fix this?

Comment: What's self.batch_size? are you sure dataA and dataB aren't empty?